# Creating an arraylist with words and comparing it to a message inputted from the user

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am new to java and i am building an android studio application. I have a chat where the user can input a message. Is it possible to create an array list containing certain words.
eg.

List listL = new ArrayList<>();

```
  listL.add("one");

  listL.add("two");

  listL.add("three");
```

And if the user has inputted any of these words i can prompt a message. Eg:  If the user has inputted "one".

I have tried

```
if (message.contains((CharSequence) listL)){

            Toast.makeText(Chat.this,"This message contains a word on the array list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

My Application Then crashes with the following error.

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check the text when some button clicked.
you can use this code in your button's onClickListener

```
if(yourList.contains(edittext.getText().toString()){
//show your message
}
```

You currently trying to find your list in your input text but you need to try find your input text in your list and you can't cast your list to CharSequence because it's Arraylist.

If you want to watch your edittext for changes, use

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
        int count) {
        if(list.contains(s)) { 
            //do your work here 
        }
}



public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {

}

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking if the list contains the input, rather than the other way around,

```
if (listL.contains(message))
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line `(message.contains((CharSequence) listL))` you are trying to cast a list to a CharSequence and you are passing it to the contains method. The exception is telling you that you cannot cast a list to a CharSequence.

What you should do is `listL.contains(message)`.

Answer (score 0):

We'll the answer is quite simple. You are casting a List to a CharSequence which is off course impossible.

You should be checking the list if it contains the String (or CharSequence).

```java
if (listL.contains(message)) {
    ...
}
```

Also you might want to use a Set for this. It is a collection of non-duplicate elements.

```java
Set<String> listL = new HashSet<String>();

listL.add("one");
...

if (listL.contains(message)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
ArrayList<String> listFilter = new ArrayList<>();

for (String mWord : listL) {
    if (listL.contains((message))){
        listFilter.add(mWord);
    }
}
```

**listFilter** is filter array list

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<String> listL=new ArrayList<>();
        listL.add("one");
        listL.add("two");
        listL.add("three");
        if (listL.toString().contains("two"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(Chat.this,"This message contains a word on the array list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```